# ¿como realizar una operacion matematica en un mismo input, usando javaserver faces?

Tags: java, web, jsf, primefaces, entrada

Código xhtml

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
  <title></title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
  <p:layoutUnit position="center">
    <h:form>
      <h:panelGrid columns="3" cellpadding="5">
        <h:outputText value="Numero:" />
        <p:inputText id="surname" value="#{operacion.numero}">
          <p:ajax event="blur" update="out2" listener="#{operacion.resolver()}" />
        </p:inputText>
        <h:outputText id="out2" value="#{operacion.respuestaEntera}" />
      </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
  </p:layoutUnit>
  <br />
</h:body>

</html>
```

Managed bean que permite llamar a la funcion en el xhtml

```
public class Operacion {

    private String numero;
    private String respuesta;
    private int respuestaEntera;

    public Operacion() {
    }

    public int getRespuestaEntera() {
        return respuestaEntera;
    }

    public void setRespuestaEntera(int respuestaEntera) {
        this.respuestaEntera = respuestaEntera;
    }

    public String getNumero() {
        return numero;
    }

    public void setNumero(String numero) {
        this.numero = numero;
    }

    public String getRespuesta() {
        return respuesta;
    }

    public void setRespuesta(String respuesta) {
        this.respuesta = respuesta;
    }

    public void resuelveOperacion() {
        String num1 = "";
        String num2 = "";
        int numero2 = Integer.parseInt(this.numero);
        for (int x = 0; x < numero.length(); x++) {
            if (numero.charAt(1) == '+') {
                if (numero == null) {
                    num1 = numero;
                } else {
                    num2 = numero;
                }
            }
            int suma = Integer.parseInt(num1) + Integer.parseInt(num2);
            respuestaEntera = suma;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: `resuelveOperacion` va a dar una excepción siempre.

Answer (score 0):

**En principio tu vista es correcta, mostrará y recogerá la información tal y como lo tienes planteado.**

Solo recordarte que es recomendable en primefaces utilizar la etiqueta p siempre que quieras hacer uso de un componente de primefaces ejemplo:

```
<p:outputLabel for="@next" value="Numero:" /> <!-- @next o surname lo que prefieras-->
<p:inputText id="surname" value... /> <!-- surname supongo que sean numero -->
```

Pero lo anterior no es un problema, tu código de vista es correcto.

**El problema lo tienes en resuelveOperacion()**

En la pregunta no se queda del todo claro que pretendes hacer en este método, pero no va a funcionarte.

```
1 int numero2 = Integer.parseInt(this.numero);
2 for (int x = 0; x < numero.length(); x++) {
```

En la línea de codigo 1 tratas a numero como un string al cual transformas a entero, perfecto si escribes "3" -> 3.

En la linea 2 vas a recorrer el String numero para buscar un "+" -> INCORRECTO, o es un número o es una operación, no puede ser los dos.

Suponiendo que sean una operación lo que esperas en la variable número tendrías lo siguiente -> CASO BÁSICO para 2+3 por ejemplo

```
public void resuelveOperacion() {
int num1 = 0;
int num2 = 0;
String regex = "+"; //Dale un par de vueltas a tu expresión regular

// analyzing the string y suponiendo que se ha entrado "2 + 3" de lo contrario 
// para "2 + " daría un error de arrayoutofboundexception
String[] numeros = this.numero.split(regex);
if (numero.contains("+")) {
    num1= Integer.parseInt(numeros[0]);
    num2= Integer.parseInt(numeros[1]);
    return num1 + num2;
}
```

}

Ahora te toca darle un par de vueltas para hacerlo genérico y poder utilizar operaciones del tipo "3 * 2 + 1" o ya más avanzado 1 + (3 * 2).

Pista: En tu expresión regular "`regex`", puedes buscar por números y operadores de manera que el array de "`String[] numeros`" sea [3, *, 2, +, 1] y solo tienes que recorrerlo buscando operadores y haciendo dicha operaciones entre los elementos [x-1] op [x+1] comprobando que tu formula es correcta [x+1] siempre exista "3+" para la posición x=1 -> x[1]=+ [x-1]=3 [x+1]=ERROR. Tienes que capturarlo o no permitir este tipo de situaciones "3+", "+3", ¿"++2"?, ¿"2++"?..

Espero que te sea de utilidad.